# Ask Ubuntu swag for top users

Tags: discussion

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- Ask Ubuntu t-shirt in your size
- Ask Ubuntu die-cut, vinyl stickers
- [Stack Exchange sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies)
- [Stack Exchange pen](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens)
- [Stack Exchange stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers)

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### T-Shirt

[image: askubuntu.com Tshirt]

### Sticker

[image: askubuntu.com sticker]

The rest of the items you can view in the [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com) — direct links to [sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies), [pens](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens), [stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers).

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- the limited edition t-shirts and stickers will be available for purchase from the store soon as well)</sub>

Comment: Quite generous, thanks!

Comment: Wow sweet thanks

Comment: Cool. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is so cool! Special thanks to Jorge for nagging me weekly to answer questions. ;)

Comment: Woo! swag!​​​​​

Comment: What a surprise! Thank you for the swag package!

Comment: This is awesome, I can't yet believe it but thank you, very much. :) I really appreciate a lot this site whose dynamic gives a reason to come online, at least for me and having this site is the best prize for me... mmmm closely followed by this swag... hahaha

Comment: This is SOO COOL!!! THANK YOU!! GRACIAS!!

Comment: <3 My colleagues think I am nuts, but I am jumping with joy :D Thanks Jeff :)

Comment: Woo hoo! Thank you very much, Jeff! I haven't been able to contribute anything to AskUbuntu this year, but I'll be back in 2012. Marco Ceppi, Stefano Palazzo, Oli,  Jorge Castro, George Edison, Roland Taylor, TheX, and everybody else on AskUbuntu: "Have a splendid year! You guys rock!" No one on the corner have swagga like us! :)

Comment: This has made my day. Many Thanks, I will repay my debt by making a real effort to get those questions answered. Cheers guys.

Comment: Awesome! I was quite surprised when I got the mail though. :P

Comment: OH MAN! I'm not in the list... But i'm on the 3rd page. May I get that Awesome Askubuntu.com t-shirt Please??

Comment: Sweet! Nice gesture.

Comment: damn nice!!!! :D

Comment: Will we be informed about the dispatch ? I should have attached my contact number as well :)

Comment: Just a little heads-up. What is going on with that swag? Did anyone receive it already.

Comment: @OctavianDamiean Swag arrived.

Comment: Want! No page 3??? :(

Comment: Just got mine too!

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that my package arrived in the mail today. Thank you again for the t-shirt and accessories. The shirt looks awesome and I look forward to wearing it around!

Comment: Mine has arrived too, thanks :)

Comment: Finally mine got delivered to Austria. Thakns alot.

Comment: Still waiting here for mine in Venezuela. But I do not want to look like htorque.. he looks like a TROLL!!

Comment: Mine got delivered today...THANKS

Comment: Just in case it does not arrive is there a way to tell someone it did not get here?

Answer (score 14):

**THANKS!**

[image]

Comment: You look oddly familiar. Haven't I seen you surfing the internet?

Comment: I'm everywhere!

Answer (score 6):

How long till we can expect our beloved swag to arrive in the mail??

Comment: Nothing here as yet

Answer (score 4):

Is there any time limit (within reason, of course) on when we need to reply by? I'm between houses at the moment (that is to say, I don't really have a fixed address) but I don't want to miss out.

It might be a week or two before I'm sure I know where I'll be. Is it okay to hold off until then or do I need to submit something ASAP?

Comment: i want to know too.

Comment: In my experience with the other sites, it's OK if you don't fill it out your info right away due to moving. Once you move(even after we had shipped the initial batch) just let us know your new address and we'll send the package to your new address.

Answer (score 4):

My swag arrived today, and I'd figured I'd make you all drool with pictures, then I thought "Eh, no need to make you all hate me", so I decided to write a thank-you note instead.

So, here's my thank-you note to the Stack Exchange team.

Thanks guys, you rock, I have no words to say, just a huge "Thank you!!!".

Oh, and Mr. Spolsky, thanks for signing the letter, I'm going to frame it. (seriously)

Oh, and if you really want pictures, [here they are](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jrgifford/sets/72157627915634148/with/6253912195/).

Comment: I'm from the Netherlands and have just received the stuff as well. It looks great! For the interested, the letter was signed off at October 4, 2011 and the date on the enveloppe says 10/13/2011.

Answer (score 4):

You guys are so generous! I was already happy with the swag I received about a month ago, but now I've got more post addressed at me containing an Ask Ubuntu swag.

I guess it's a mistake, but I'm still very happy with it. Thanks Jeff and your Stack Exchange team!

[bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bug)

Comment: I got a second package yesterday! If you send me a new SE pen every month, perhaps I can actually use it on a regular basis, without fearing it is gonna run out and I'll be without!

Comment: I also received another package today and was wondering if this was done intentionally. Thank you for the additional package.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wondering about what to choose for size: XL in the US is not the same as XL in Europe. If I rememberd correctly: size US XL is equal to Europe's XXL.

Jeff: If I want to change the size how would I do that? :)

Comment: sizing info is at http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/823/webapps-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users/826#826 .. was also linked in the form itself where you select a size.

Answer (score 2):

WOOOOOOOHOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!!!!

It just arrived today!!!

Thank you very much!!! You guys are awesome!!! I love this stuff!!! Thank you!!!

This is the best gift I have received in the past 20 years :D Thank you!!! Really representative... Awesome!!! I am amazed!!! And the T-Shirt is my size!!! fits perfectly!!!

LOL I am happy!!!

A picture is here for you! I didn't expect this to come, I thought that you missed my message but you got it!!! hahaha Thank you!!! I really appreciate this!!!

Somehow I can't put a picture right now but you can see my gift in this link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/geppettvs/6306411627/

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Today I got IT!!!! WHOOHOO!!. Am going to go to the nearest geek party and walk around... slooowwllyy.. groovy style. Ohh yeah! You know you are cool when you got that shirt and you are level 85.

Answer (score 1):

I'm from Venezuela, when it gets here I will let everybody know. This is awesome!

Comment: warning: it will be a minimum of 6-8 weeks from the date this was posted, so not terribly soon!

Comment: We can wait that long >:-D :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm from Nepal. Well I kinda filled medium for t-shirt but seems my t-shirt size is large so I kinda filled the form twice. I hope you guys will pardon the error. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to let you know that my package arrived in the mail today.

Thank you again for the t-shirt and accessories. The shirt looks awesome and I look forward to wearing it around!

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently living in China with my girlfriend and have no idea how to write my apartment's address in English so I just wrote the address that's on my girlfriend's business card.

"no matter where in the world you live." - let's see :)

By the way, did anyone receive the swag yet?

Comment: No swag yet here. :(

Answer (score 0):

i got that e-mal and send it ... sorry a lost that e-mail because my box dead but i didn't receive nothing jet ......

anyway thxs for the present ....

and regards.,

UPDATE

You are so fast guys i' just receive my t-shirt now thx for the gift and good luck