# What is the use of having badges?

Tags: discussion, support

In AU apart from reputation there is something called 'Badges'. But I see that no privilege requires a badge nor is it used for placing a bounty or anything else. So why do I need badges for? Is it just for fun? ! Sometimes a user who has lesser reputation has a larger number of badges than the one that has greater reputation. Isn't this contradictory ?

Comment: Sometimes we do things for fun!

Comment: @JorgeCastro Are you serious? ! Thats all it is... FUN ?? !!! 0_o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Badges are basically for fun BUT you can tell if someone is active on AU and contributes.

The more gold badges for great answers and the more (silver) guru-badges the more you probably can trust that user to get it correct.

Reputation is more important [since you get swag](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1699/ask-ubuntu-swag-for-top-users)!!