# Ask Ubuntu still sending packages to top users?

Tags: discussion

while reading questions on meta,I read this one.

[Ask Ubuntu swag for top users](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1699/ask-ubuntu-swag-for-top-users)

Does it still present ?

Does it happened after Beta period ?

Comment: Just got one with with a letter inside saying "You're on page 3. We're sorry."

Comment: how?...which link you clicked ? @kos

Comment: Nevermind, It was just a *very bad* joke.

Comment: I don't think they're still sending them, it looks like a one-time thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I got swag when I reached 100k *o*

Part of the mail:

> ... But getting a big ole box of cool stuff from our sites is also a fun
>   way to mark the occasion, so we put together a collection of swag for
>   you. It's just a small token of our appreciation for everything you've
>   done. ...

And I got ...

- An American sized mug
- SE stickers;
- AU T-shirt
- AU stickers
- Notebook

within a few days after I got the mail. In less than 98k rep you will get it too.

But the one you refer to was a 1 time thing (that could be repeated at some point).